# How do you specify the username in ftp upload by a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, ftp, cmd

I want to make a batch that auto uploads important files from the user that is using the program. so what I did was %username% in the directory Ex. C:\user\%username%\importantfiles

```
open (ftp server name)
(ftp user-name)
(ftp password)
prompt
bin
mput c:\user\%username%\importantfiles
```

There are many users that must be able to use this..

So the "C:\user\mike\importantfiles" will not work

So the question is **How do you specify the username in ftp upload**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to generate the ftp script file from your batch.

Something like (just a skeleton)

```
....
set "ftpScript=%temp%\%~nx0.ftp.tmp"
(
    echo open (ftp server name)
    echo (ftp user-name)
    echo (ftp password)
    echo prompt
    echo bin
    echo mput "c:\user\%username%\importantfiles\*.*"
    echo quit
) > "%ftpScript%"

ftp -s:"%ftpScript%"
del /q "%ftpScript%" >nul 2>nul
....
```

Comment: I haven't tested - but should you use `lcd "c:\user\%username%\importantfiles\"` and then `mput *.*` ?  I'm not sure how Windows FTP handles paths in the commands.

Comment: @foxidrive, at least in windows 7 it works. For me, it gives two errors because the `*.*` matchs the `.` and `..` folders, but files get uploaded.

Comment: Thanks for testing it for me, I should have tested earlier.  If you use `path\*` then it still has a harmless error on those items BTW, as well as on folders.